# DbFlow Kotlin and List<String> Type Converter

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, dbflow

DBFlow Version: 4.0.4
Hi, I'm strugling with List Type converter with dbflow Android ORM and Kotlin. I have a data class defined like this:

```
@Table(database = StopsDb::class)
data class FavouriteStop(
        @PrimaryKey @Column var id: String = "",
        @Index @Column var name: String = "",
        @Column(typeConverter = StringListConverter::class) var directions: List<String> = listOf(),
        @Column(typeConverter = StringListConverter::class) var selectedDirections: List<String> = listOf()
) : BaseRXModel()
```

and as I don't want to create a separate table only to store Strings I created a List Type converter like this:

```
class StringListConverter : TypeConverter<String, List<String>>() {

    val separator = ","

    override fun getDBValue(model: List<String>?): String {
        if(model==null || model.isEmpty())
            return ""
        else
            return model.joinToString (separator = separator){ it }
    }

    override fun getModelValue(data: String?): List<String> {
        return data?.split(separator) ?: listOf()
    }
}
```

however following error is thrown during build phase:

```
Error:error: *==========* :The specified custom TypeConverter's Model Value java.util.List<? extends java.lang.String> from com.kapuscinski.departures.persistence.db.StringListConverter must match the type of the column java.util.List<java.lang.String>.*==========*
```

Am I missing something here, and how to fix this? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Change everything from "List" to "MutableList"

```
@Table(database = StopsDb::class)
data class FavouriteStop(
        @PrimaryKey @Column var id: String = "",
        @Index @Column var name: String = "",
        @Column(typeConverter = StringListConverter::class) var directions: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
        @Column(typeConverter = StringListConverter::class) var selectedDirections: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
) : BaseRXModel()

class StringListConverter : TypeConverter<String, MutableList<String>>() {
    val separator = ","

    override fun getDBValue(model: MutableList<String>?): String =
            if (model == null || model.isEmpty())
                ""
            else
                model.joinToString(separator = separator) { it }

    override fun getModelValue(data: String?): MutableList<String> {
        return data?.split(separator)?.toMutableList() ?: mutableListOf()
    }
}
```